# How do I disable the Cassandra connection while running test cases?

Tags: cassandra, spring-webflux

While running the test cases, it is trying to connect cassandra hosts, i have tried different approaches to disable the cassandra connection.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = \
  { \
    CassandraAutoConfiguration.class, \
    CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class, \
    CassandraReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class \
  }
)
```

Above one also not working.

How to disable cassandra connection while running test cases using mvn test. Please suggest me any other approach

disable cassandra connection while running test cases using mvn test

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) steps to replicate the problem. For guidance, see https://stackexchange.com/tour and https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can run 'nodetool disablebinary' on the Cassandra side to disable native transport connectivity.  When you are ready to resume, run 'nodetool enablebinary'.